# Qt Reading Xml File QXmlStreamReader - stuck in a loop

Tags: xml, qt

Heres the format of XML I want to read:

```
<base>
    <pasta>name
      <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
      <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
      <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
      <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
    </pasta>
    <pasta>name2
      <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
      <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
    </pasta>
</base>
```

The code I am using to read the xml:

```
QList<PastaBase>* BaseWrapper::carregarDeXml(QString caminhoArquivoXml)
{
    //Carrega do XML
    QFile arquivoXml(caminhoArquivoXml);
    if(!arquivoXml.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QString s(QString::fromUtf8("Erro ao abrir arquivo de base"));
        QMessageBox::warning(0, "Erro", s);
        throw QString("Erro ao abrir arquivo de base");
    }
    QList<PastaBase> *base = new QList<PastaBase>();
    QXmlStreamReader r;
    r.setDevice(&arquivoXml);
    while(!r.atEnd() && !r.hasError())
    {
        r.readNext();

        if(r.isStartElement())
        {
            if(r.name().toString() == QString("pasta"))
            {
                PastaBase p;
                p.setNome(r.readElementText());
                r.readNextStartElement();
                while(r.name().toString() == QString("musica"))
                {
                    std::cout << "elemento: " << r.name().toLatin1().constData() << " - valor: " << r.readElementText().toLatin1().constData() << std::endl;
                    p.getMidias()->append(r.readElementText());
                    r.readNextStartElement();
                }
                base->append(p);
            }
        }
    }
    arquivoXml.close();
    return base;
}
```

The output - stuck in while loop:

```
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor: 
elemento: musica - valor:
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that's the code you're running? I tried to copy/paste it but it doesn't compile...

`r.name()` returns a [QStringRef](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstringref.html) and there is no `toLatin1()` method in it. If I replace it by the `toString()` method then it compiles fine for me.

But your problem isn't there, I think what you're doing in your xml file is illegal:

```
<pasta>you can't put something here
  <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
  <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
  <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
  <musica>my audio.mp3</musica>
</pasta>
```

The line that is causing the infinite loop is `p.setNome(r.readElementText());` because you must not type text here if you have subtags in it.

I'm not very familiar with XML but I really think your problem is here. Can anyone confirm that please?

Comment: I dont know why but QStringRef.toLatin1() is compiling and working here.

Comment: As for the XML child I think you can put text there...I have another application written in Java that write this XML....and I have another C++ Qt method that saves a xml in this format working